# Listview in kendo mobile is not binding to observable object in mvvm pattern

Tags: javascript, listview, mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I am using [kendoui](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/) library to build a mobile application. I am having a problem in listing the data in listview. I am binding my listview to the observable *itemViewModel*   But it seems it is not binding well, it seems its a silly error in the code. This is the code.

**javascript**

```
var itemViewModel = new kendo.observable({
item: {
    name: " a name",
    price: 30
},
itemDataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [{
        name: "cover",
        price: 20
    }, {
        name: "charger",
        price: 20
    }, {
        name: "bag",
        price: 30
    }]
})
});

var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body);
```

**Html**

```
    <div data-role="view" data-title="Views" id="item-list-view"  data-layout="mobile-layout" data-bind="itemViewModel" >

        <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset"  data-type="group">
            <li id="itemslist">For Sale

                <ul
                     data-role="listview"
                     data-style="inset"  
                     data-type="group"
                    data-template="item-list-template"
                    data-bind="source:itemDataSource">

                  </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
     <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="item-list-template">
        <li><a href="\#item-form-view">#= name # <span class="sales-hold">&rarr; $ #= price #</span></a></li>
    </script>
```

This is a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Pro_Bro_1/A4FrT/) to the code.

If the code is fine.

My question : Is it enough to just instantiate the kendo.mobile.application in order to bind the view to the modelView or I want to do anything else?

Please I need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the **data-bind="itemViewModel"** it should be **data-model="itemViewModel"** .

```
 <div data-role="view" data-title="Views" id="item-list-view"  data-layout="mobile-layout"       data-model="itemViewModel" >
  ........
  ....the rest of my code 
  ........
  </div>
```